# How to do I embed an Angular App without CORS issues

Tags: angular, cors

I am an angular newbie. Please go easy.

I have a legacy webapp which is running on http://localhost:55540/. We are wanting to load the Angular App (named Angular8ClientCrud) WITHIN this app. It is doing a straight GET to load the angular transpiled content (it does a GET to http://localhost:4000/Angular8ClientCrud/index.html and loads the content) on the page. Dist folder:

[image: dist folder]

The index.html file looks like:

[image]

When we try to load the page, we do a GET and the load the http://localhost:4000/Angular8ClientCrud/index.html, we get the CORS issue:

[image]

How do I make the JS files build in such a way that they accept requests from any origin -

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

In IIS I set the access-control-allow-origin header to *

[image]